# Nested async callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to learn exactly how async works in JavaScript. 
In the example below I'm doing a nested database lookup inside the callback of another async database call (in the example I'm just using `setTimeout`)

The way I'm trying to keep track of when I'm done going through all the products including the nested database call is by incrementing a variable called `index` and checking for `index == fake_data.length`.

This database library does not support Promises out of the box, so I'm really unsure what else to do. This just doesn't seem like the right way of doing it.

```
const fake_data = [{ type: 4 }, { type: 4 }, { type: 1 }, { type: 1 }, { 
type: 4 }, { type: 3 }, { type: 2 }];

const products = [];

function test() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let index = 0;
        fake_data.forEach(product => {
            if (products.filter(p => p.type == product.type).length == 0) {
                products.push(product);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    index++;
                    if (index == fake_data.length) {
                        test2();
                    }
                }, 400)

            }
            else {
                index++;
            }
            console.log("index", index);
        })
    }, 1200);

}


function test2() {
    console.log(`Wooow, i have some many unique types here`);
    products.forEach(p => console.log(p.type));
}
```

I feel like I have missed something very basic  somewhere...

Comment: This isn't about your main question, but are you sure about `products.filter(p => p.type == product.type).length == 0)` This will be true only when filter finds nothing, but you've set it up so the filter *always* finds something.

Comment: @Mark_M I'm pretty sure that it will only return true if there's no product with the same type in `products`. Console.logs: `New type 4 Already exists New type 1 Already exists Already exists New type 3
New type 2`.

Comment: My mistake @jones — I thought `products` was your `fake_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your callback style code to promise based. Have a look here http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html

Or you can use this snippet https://gist.github.com/joelnet/ece690e942223954b1b7997ba3b1cb00#file-promisify-js

```
function promisify(func) {
  return (...args) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const callback = (err, data) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)

      func.apply(this, [...args, callback])
  })
}
```

Comment: So the solution is to add a 3rd party package? Hmm.

Comment: @jones Updated my answer

Comment: Cool thanks, I'm having trouble applying it to the example however but this looks to be the solution

Comment: promisify is also in node core: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what your question is here, but it looks as though you are trying to simulate db calls using `setTimeout`, and want to just *play around* with promises. If that is correct, I would suggest creating separate functions that act as your db layer, so that they could be swapped out with the real thing. If you want to use `setTimeout`, then wrap it in a promise too. Something like:

```
const fake_data = [{ type: 4 }, { type: 4 }, { type: 1 }, { type: 1 }, { type: 4 }, { type: 3 }, { type: 2 }];

// this just wraps setTimeout in a promise
const simulateWork = (time, func) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(func()), time)
  })
}

const getProducts = () => simulateWork(1200, () => fake_data)
const handleProduct = product => simulateWork(400, () => {
  // do something with a product after some time
})

// the you can call things like
getProducts.then(products => {
  products.forEach(handleProduct)
})
```

---

Update:

So, it looks like you want to do a bunch of async things, and then do something once it all completes. A good candidate for this is [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), where you pass an array of async promise work, which doesn't finish until all tasks have resolved.

using the above helper functions, you could do something like the following:

```
// function to get unique objects
const getUnique = (arr, getVal) => {
  var hash = {}
  var output = []
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(!hash[getVal(item)]){
      hash[getVal(item)] = true
      output.push(item)
    }
  }
  return output
}

getProducts.then(products => {
  // get a list of unique products and map to new work
  Promise.all(getUnique(products, p => p.type).map(product => handleProduct))
    // this will be called once all data completed
    .then(() => test2())
}
```

Comment: The overall idea is to make a nested async database call to fetch additional data and save it for unique products. Since it's async, I'm using `index` to prevent calling `test2()` too early before getting all the data if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, I think you need promise.all. I have updated my answer.